# emacs and pasting from clipboard gives this "don\u2019t know"

Tags: emacs

How can I stop this happening please, when I import text from the debian clipboard into emacs like this source text

```
Remember, most breast lumps are not cancerous, but you don’t know if you don’t ask.
```

it appears in the buffer as

```
Remember, most breast lumps are not cancerous, but you don\u2019t know if you don\u2019t ask
```

So how can I get rid of all the \u2019, and all characters like that please? This is with emacs 24.3.90.1 and default fonts, on debian jessie.

Comment: use global search and replace....

Comment: I've tried that, but they are some kind of special character as they can be deleted with one key-press, and search and replace does not work on them

Answer (score 0):

Probably You have wrong default coding sytem or method. Try the following:

```
(set-language-environment 'UTF-8)
(setq default-input-method "cyrillic-translit")
```